# When using sails-disk any attribute with `unique:true` must also have `required:true`

Tags: sails.js

I am using Sails 1.1.0 and sails-disk.

I have one-to-one relationship. A task must have a message. Even though I set required to true in the `Task.message` relationship, I keep getting error "In attribute `message` of model `task`: When using sails-disk, any attribute with `unique: true` must also have `required: true`". Anyone know how to fix? My code is:

```
/api/models/Task.js

message: {
      model: 'message',
      required: true,
      unique: true
},

/api/models/Message.js

task: {
      collection: 'task',
      via: 'message'
},
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is a bug in `sails-disk` - https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/4559